# Asking about data set multiplication in R

Tags: r, for-loop, matrix-multiplication

I have two data set "A" with 2000 rows and 1000 columns, and "B" with 5 rows and 1000 columns. Now I want to create the third data set C with 2000 rows and 5 rows. Each cell in C is a linear combination of 1000 cells from A and 1000 cells from B.

```
A <- as.data.frame(matrix(0, nrow=2000,ncol=1000))


B <- as.data.frame(matrix(0, nrow=5,ncol=1000))
```

I know a very straightforward way to create C:

```
for (i in 1:2000) { 
      for (j in 1:5)  {
      C[i,j] <- A[i,1]*B[j,1] + A[i,2]*B[J,2] + ....+ A[i,1000]*B[j,1000]
                       }
      }
```

But I'll have to write very long code manually. I am asking for any guidance on a much easier and readable code.

Thanks so much in advance!

Comment: `C = as.matrix(A) %*% t(B)`?

Comment: You can actually *show* the sample data and your expected output if you used something less than 2000. Perhaps, 10x5 and 5x5, respectively. Also, while I applaud the programmatic sample data, having a matrix of all zeroes does not necessarily show any of the results from the math.

Comment: Thanks so much for d.b's guidance and r2evans's suggestions!